# Is finite subset of a set which contains all non regular languages a regular set?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, undecidability

Let A be a set which contains all non-regular languages. Then set B which is finite subset of A. Then will it be regular ?

I know that A is not recursive enumerable set (undecidable). So I wonder that if finite subset of undecidable set is a regular language or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense because of a category error. "Regular" is a property of sets of strings. A set of languages is a set of sets of strings, so it doesn't make sense to ask if it's regular.

Comment: Accepted the fact. thanks!